# Unable to install grub. Partition outside the disk

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, gparted

When Ubuntu is installing on Sony Vaio VPCZ11Z9E from pendrive I have this error:

`Unable to install GRUB in /dev/sda
Executing 'grub-install/dev/sda' failed.
This is fatal error.`

Part of output from `sudo fdisk -l` for sda device:

`Disk /dev/sda: 59.6 GiB, 64023257088 bytes, 125045424 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xc5f114c5
Device     Boot   Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1          2048    999423    997376  487M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       1001470 500162559 499161090  238G  5 Extended`

I don't know is it important, but when  I turn on GParted i have error on the start:

`Libparted Error
Can't have a partition outside the disk`

When I ignore it I see that I have 6 devices:

`/dev/mapper/isw_dccdjaajf_Volume0 (238,50 GiB)
/dev/sda                          (59,63 GiB)
/dev/sdb                          (59,63 GiB)
/dev/sdc                          (59,63 GiB)
/dev/sdd                          (59,63 GiB)
/dev/sde                          (14,51 GiB)`

Help me, please

Comment: delete the extended partition. according to fdisk it ends at sector 500K but the disk only has 125K sectors

Comment: @ravery I try to deleted this partition through GParted and `sudo fdisk /dev/sda` with `2` , `d` command, but when I typed `sudo fdisk -l` nothing has changed

Comment: is there anything on the disk you need? you could wipe it with `dd` and repartition

Comment: I don't need anything from disk. I deleted sda2 and divide sda into parts, but next errors came about /dev/mapper...

Comment: U had right. When I delete partitions in /dev/sda and restart computer, /dev/mapper.. disapear. I repartition dev/sda correctly and everything work fine. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and tried everything. The way I fixed it was take the hard drive out of the computer and put in a hard drive enclosure. I booted up the iMac and used the disk utility, formated the drive and installed Ubuntu 17.10. Sound amateurish but worked. I installed Ubuntu 17.10 and all is well.Now I'm looking for a better solution here, but didn't.